# JS is not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was just coding some stuff, but then I added (or deleted) something and all of the JS code stopped working.(everything else was fine)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style>
      .embed-test {
      color:maroon;
      font-family: Cursive;
     }
.embed2{
      font-size:50px;
     }
.stpd{
      font-family:Comic Sans MS;
     }
th,
td{
      border:2px solid black;
      font-family:Arial;
      color:#000010;
      font-size:25px;
      text-align:center;
  }
table{
      border:3px solid black;
     }
      .tf{
        width:200px
      }
.JS{
      padding: 0.75em 1.25em;
      background-color:whitesmoke;
      width:10em
      }
.imp{
      background-color:black;
      font-family:Arial;
      color:white;
      font-size:200px;
      letter-spacing:5px;
      width:6em;
      padding: 0.25em 0.25em;
      }
.arinf{
      font-size:20px;
      font-family: Arial;
      }
.JS2{
      padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
      background-color:gray;
      width:12em;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size:20px;
      }
.ce{
      border: 2px solid black;
   }
.hidden{
      display: none;
       }
.pass{
      width: 200px;
      margin-top:1px;
      font-size:20px;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'>
      //IDK
      $('.arinf').toggle();
      //Submit form
      //Click Me
      $('.JS').on('click',function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).fadeIn(1000);
          })
      //arrow.io info
       $('.JS2').on('click', function(){
          if()
          $('#hidd').removeClass('hidden');
          $('.arinf').slideToggle();
           });
      //Veryuglybutton
         $('.hidden').fadeOut(500);
       $('.ignoreplz').on('click',function(){
         $('.ignore').fadeOut(1000);
         $('.ignoreplz').fadeOut(4000);
         })
       //此非詐騙集團
       alert('恭喜你來到了這個網頁,點擊OK繼續')
    </script>
    <h1>61602 :)</h1>
    <p>要看程式碼</p>
    <p>按Ctrl+U</p>

    <p>全部都是我寫的</p>
    <p>我中打很慢,所以這個網頁幾乎是全英文的XD</p>
    <form>
      輸入代碼:<br>
      <input type='text' name='passw' class='pas'><br>
      <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit'>
    </form>
    <nav>
      <a href="#1">1</a>
      <a href="#2">2</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <h1>Blank Page, Used for Coding Practicing and Testing</h1>
    <p> edited through NotePad</p>
    <h3 class="embed-test"> CSS in HTML using style tag</h3>
    <h3 class="embed2"> test 2</h3>
    <p style="color:green">GREEN/</p>
    <h2>TABLE TEST</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th class="tf">Desc</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Howard</td>
            <td class="stpd tf">Stoopid</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     <h2>JS EMBED TEST</h2>
     <h6>Imcomplete</h6>
     <p class="JS">Click Me</p>
     <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
     <p>Click!</p>
     <p>Size comp</p>
     <h1>h1</h1>
     <h2>h2</h2>
     <h3>h3</h3>
     <h4>h4</h4>
     <h5>h5</h5>
     <h6>h6</h6>
     <p>p</p>
     <p class="JS2">Click to show arrow.io info</p>
     <div id="hidd" class="arinf hidden">
       <h1 class="imp"><strong>IMPORTANT</strong><br />arrow.io</h1>
       <h1>7: vivi</h1>
       <h1>3: 曾宥程</h1>
       <h1>5: poo</h1>
       <h1>2: MCS</h1>
     </div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="ce"></div>
     <button class="ignoreplz">Very<b>ugly</b>button<b>do</b>not<b>press</b></button>
     <blockquote class="ignore"><i><b>Hi.This is some random text that you should not care about.Plz ignore this<br />ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<br />abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</b></i></blockquote>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S. Im new and sorry if there was too much code there that was the entire page
and Stackover just keeps telling me to add more details to it so im just filling it up xd

Comment: How would we possibly be able to help?? Also, saying its "its not working" is extremely bad manners.

Comment: More details like "What is the error message"

Comment: You can not have an external script and internal script in the same tag. I am too lazy to find the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

**use script tag like this**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
    <style>
      .embed-test {
      color:maroon;
      font-family: Cursive;
     }
.embed2{
      font-size:50px;
     }
.stpd{
      font-family:Comic Sans MS;
     }
th,
td{
      border:2px solid black;
      font-family:Arial;
      color:#000010;
      font-size:25px;
      text-align:center;
  }
table{
      border:3px solid black;
     }
      .tf{
        width:200px
      }
.JS{
      padding: 0.75em 1.25em;
      background-color:whitesmoke;
      width:10em
      }
.imp{
      background-color:black;
      font-family:Arial;
      color:white;
      font-size:200px;
      letter-spacing:5px;
      width:6em;
      padding: 0.25em 0.25em;
      }
.arinf{
      font-size:20px;
      font-family: Arial;
      }
.JS2{
      padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
      background-color:gray;
      width:12em;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size:20px;
      }
.ce{
      border: 2px solid black;
   }
.hidden{
      display: none;
       }
.pass{
      width: 200px;
      margin-top:1px;
      font-size:20px;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>61602 :)</h1>
    <p>要看程式碼</p>
    <p>按Ctrl+U</p>

    <p>全部都是我寫的</p>
    <p>我中打很慢,所以這個網頁幾乎是全英文的XD</p>
    <form>
      輸入代碼:<br>
      <input type='text' name='passw' class='pas'><br>
      <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit'>
    </form>
    <nav>
      <a href="#1">1</a>
      <a href="#2">2</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <h1>Blank Page, Used for Coding Practicing and Testing</h1>
    <p> edited through NotePad</p>
    <h3 class="embed-test"> CSS in HTML using style tag</h3>
    <h3 class="embed2"> test 2</h3>
    <p style="color:green">GREEN/</p>
    <h2>TABLE TEST</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th class="tf">Desc</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Howard</td>
            <td class="stpd tf">Stoopid</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     <h2>JS EMBED TEST</h2>
     <h6>Imcomplete</h6>
     <p class="JS">Click Me</p>

     <p>Click!</p>
     <p>Size comp</p>
     <h1>h1</h1>
     <h2>h2</h2>
     <h3>h3</h3>
     <h4>h4</h4>
     <h5>h5</h5>
     <h6>h6</h6>
     <p>p</p>
     <p class="JS2">Click to show arrow.io info</p>
     <div id="hidd" class="arinf hidden">
       <h1 class="imp"><strong>IMPORTANT</strong><br />arrow.io</h1>
       <h1>7: vivi</h1>
       <h1>3: 曾宥程</h1>
       <h1>5: poo</h1>
       <h1>2: MCS</h1>
     </div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="ce"></div>
     <button class="ignoreplz">Very<b>ugly</b>button<b>do</b>not<b>press</b></button>
     <blockquote class="ignore"><i><b>Hi.This is some random text that you should not care about.Plz ignore this<br />ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<br />abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</b></i></blockquote>
     <script>
      //IDK
      $('.arinf').toggle();
      //Submit form
      //Click Me
      $('.JS').on('click',function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).fadeIn(1000);
          })
      //arrow.io info
       $('.JS2').on('click', function(){
          if()
          $('#hidd').removeClass('hidden');
          $('.arinf').slideToggle();
           });
      //Veryuglybutton
         $('.hidden').fadeOut(500);
       $('.ignoreplz').on('click',function(){
         $('.ignore').fadeOut(1000);
         $('.ignoreplz').fadeOut(4000);
         });
      alert("your error")
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**working codepen link**
https://codepen.io/crowm/pen/eVpZYB

Answer (score 0):

You can not combine external script with the inline/internal one.

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'>
  //IDK
  $('.arinf').toggle();
```

Your code needs to be

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'><script>
<script>
  //IDK
  $('.arinf').toggle();
```